# How to create a file only if it doesn't exist

Tags: haskell, posix

In C, I can call `open` with `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` to create a new file if and only if there isn't currently one by that name. I haven't been able to find a way to do that in Haskell. I would prefer something friendly that provides a `Handle`, ideally with all the tricky exception handling done for me. (I don't necessarily expect it to be done for me *correctly*, but that's another story.)

Answer (score 5):

I think this isn’t available directly in `base`, but you can use [`openFd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-IO.html#v:openFd) from the [`unix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix) package, setting the `exclusive` flag in the [`OpenFileFlags`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-IO.html#t:OpenFileFlags) record to `True`. Summary:

```
openFd
  path
  WriteOnly
  (Just defaultMode)
  defaultFileFlags { exclusive = True }
```

The result of this can be converted to a normal Haskell I/O `Handle` using [`fdToHandle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-IO.html#v:fdToHandle). If it fails, it should throw an `IOError` exception, which (I think) you can test with [`isAlreadyExistsError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html#v:isAlreadyExistsError).

On Windows, this can be done with [`createFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.13.2.0/docs/System-Win32-File.html#v:createFile) from the [`Win32`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32) package.

```
createFile
  path
  gENERIC_WRITE
  fILE_SHARE_NONE
  Nothing
  cREATE_NEW
  fILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
  Nothing
```

You can then use [`hANDLEToHandle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.13.2.0/docs/System-Win32-Types.html#v:hANDLEToHandle) to get a regular `Handle`. I’m not sure how the error handling works here; you may need to check the `HANDLE` against `nullPtr` and call `getLastError` to get error info.

Comment: Thanks, that'll ... eventually ... do it. The trouble is that to be safe in the presence of multiple Haskell threads, it's necessary to be very careful when opening file descriptors to be sure not to leak them on exceptions. This was buggy in `base` until very recently, and I think may still be buggy in the handling of temp files.

Comment: Regarding Windows: I don't know the first thing about programming on that platform, so I happily leave it to other people.

Comment: @dfeuer Can't you bind the lifetime of a file-descriptor to a Haskell linear-type? Wouldn't that guarantee cleanup?

Comment: @Dai, no, that's not sufficient, and not entirely necessary in practice. Insufficient because of asynchronous exceptions.